# WCF SOAP service give an error An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/Service1.svc

Tags: wcf, soap

when i make the client and call the getNews it goes into service but after the return its give me this error

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/Service1.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.'

Interface is :

```
    [ServiceContract , XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]

    //  string getNews(getNewsRequest request);
    // GetNewsOutputStructure getNews (getNewsRequest request);
    // getNewsResponseStructure getNews(getNewsRequest request);
    getNewsResponse getNews();

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}
```

the implementation is

```
       public getNewsResponse getNews()
    {
        getNewsResponse response = null;

        List<NewsListStructure> newsList = new List<NewsListStructure>();
        NewsStructure news = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            news = new NewsStructure();
            news.NewsText = "Test";
            news.NewsId = "22";
            news.NewsDate = DateTime.Now;
            MediaExtentionsArrayStructure[] mediaExtentionsArrayStructures = null;
            news.MediaExtentionsArrayObject = mediaExtentionsArrayStructures;   //nnList[i].NewsDate;
            news.NewsClassificationObject = new NewsClassificationStructure { NewsClassificationId = 1.ToString(), NewsClassificationDescription = "g" };
            //  news.MediaArrayObject = nnList[i].NewsDate;
            NewsListStructure newsStructure = new NewsListStructure();
            newsStructure.NewsObject = news;
            newsList.Add(newsStructure);

        }
        //   return newsList;

        GetNewsOutputStructure getNewsOutputStructure = new GetNewsOutputStructure();
        getNewsOutputStructure.NewsListObject = newsList.ToArray();
        getNewsOutputStructure.ResponseStatus = ResponseStatusType.Success;
        getNewsOutputStructure.DataSchemaVersion = 1;
        getNewsOutputStructure.FaildReasonListObject = new FaildReasonListStructure[1] ;
        var fdf = new ErrorStructure() { Item = "hh" , ItemElementName = ItemChoiceType.ErrorMessage};
        getNewsOutputStructure.FaildReasonListObject[0] = new FaildReasonListStructure();
        getNewsOutputStructure.FaildReasonListObject[0].Item = fdf;
        // return  getNewsOutputStructure;

        getNewsResponseStructure getNewsResponseStructure = new getNewsResponseStructure();
        getNewsResponseStructure.Item = getNewsOutputStructure;

     // return getNewsResponseStructure;
     //   response = new getNewsResponse(getNewsResponseStructure);
        response = new getNewsResponse();
        response.getNewsResponseObject = getNewsResponseStructure;
       response.getNewsResponseObject.Item = newsList;

     return response;
    }
```

after return response i got an error
and this is the object i will return

```
    [DataContract]
public class getNewsResponse
{

    //  [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute()]
    [XmlElement]
    [DataMember]
    public getNewsResponseStructure getNewsResponseObject;

    public getNewsResponse()
    {
    }

    public getNewsResponse(getNewsResponseStructure getNewsResponseObject)
    {
        this.getNewsResponseObject = getNewsResponseObject;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class getNewsResponseStructure
{

    // [DataMember]
    private object itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("getNewsResponseDetailObject", typeof(GetNewsOutputStructure))]
    //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ServiceError", typeof(CommonErrorStructure))]
    [XmlElement]


    [DataMember]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public partial class GetNewsOutputStructure
{

    private ResponseStatusType responseStatusField;

    private NewsListStructure[] newsListObjectField;

    private FaildReasonListStructure[] faildReasonListObjectField;

    private decimal dataSchemaVersionField;


   
   // [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    [XmlElement]


    /// <remarks/>
    [DataMember]
    public ResponseStatusType ResponseStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return this.responseStatusField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.responseStatusField = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement]


    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("NewsListObject", Order = 1)]
    
    [DataMember]

    public NewsListStructure[] NewsListObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsListObjectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsListObjectField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("FaildReasonListObject", Order = 2)]
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]


    public FaildReasonListStructure[] FaildReasonListObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.faildReasonListObjectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.faildReasonListObjectField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 3)]
    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]

    public decimal DataSchemaVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dataSchemaVersionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dataSchemaVersionField = value;
        }
    }
}


[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum ResponseStatusType
{
   // [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
   [EnumMember]

    /// <remarks/>
    Success,
    //  [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    [EnumMember]

    /// <remarks/>
    Fail,
}

[DataContract]

public partial class NewsListStructure
{

    private NewsStructure newsObjectField;

    [DataMember]
    /// <remarks/>
 //   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    [XmlElement]
    public NewsStructure NewsObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsObjectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsObjectField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public partial class FaildReasonListStructure
{

    private ErrorStructure itemField;

    [DataMember]
    /// <remarks/>
 //   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ErrorObject", Order = 0)]
    [XmlElement]
    public ErrorStructure Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public partial class ErrorStructure
{

    private string itemField;

    private ItemChoiceType itemElementNameField;

    /// <remarks/>
 //   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ErrorCode", typeof(string), Order = 0)]
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ErrorMessage", typeof(string), Order = 0)]
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemElementName")]
  [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public string Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
 //   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    [XmlElement]
    public ItemChoiceType ItemElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemElementNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
[Flags]
public enum ItemChoiceType
{
   // [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
   [EnumMember]
    /// <remarks/>
    ErrorCode,
  //  [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
    [EnumMember]

    /// <remarks/>
    ErrorMessage,
}

[DataContract]
public partial class NewsStructure
{

    private string newsIdField;

    private NewsClassificationStructure newsClassificationObjectField;

    private string newsTextField;

    private MediaArrayStructure[] mediaArrayObjectField;

    private MediaExtentionsArrayStructure[] mediaExtentionsArrayObjectField;

    private System.DateTime newsDateField;

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
  [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public string NewsId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsIdField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
  [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public NewsClassificationStructure NewsClassificationObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsClassificationObjectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsClassificationObjectField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 2)]
  [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public string NewsText
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsTextField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsTextField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MediaArrayObject", Order = 3)]
  [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public MediaArrayStructure[] MediaArrayObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mediaArrayObjectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mediaArrayObjectField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MediaExtentionsArrayObject", Order = 4)]
  [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public MediaExtentionsArrayStructure[] MediaExtentionsArrayObject
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mediaExtentionsArrayObjectField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mediaExtentionsArrayObjectField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date", Order = 5)]
  [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public System.DateTime NewsDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsDateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsDateField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public partial class MediaExtentionsArrayStructure
{

    private string itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MediaExtentions", Order = 0)]
  [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public string Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public partial class MediaArrayStructure
{

    private byte[] itemField;

    [DataMember]
    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Media", DataType = "base64Binary", Order = 0)]
    [XmlElement]
    public byte[] Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public partial class NewsClassificationStructure
{

    private string newsClassificationIdField;

    private string newsClassificationDescriptionField;

    [DataMember]
    /// <remarks/>
  //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    [XmlElement]
    public string NewsClassificationId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsClassificationIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsClassificationIdField = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember]
    /// <remarks/>
 //   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    [XmlElement]
    public string NewsClassificationDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return this.newsClassificationDescriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.newsClassificationDescriptionField = value;
        }
    }


}


//[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
//[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
//[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("ExportSchema")]
//[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute]
[DataContract]

public partial class CommonErrorStructure : object, System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable
{

    private System.Xml.XmlNode[] nodesField;

    private static System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeName = new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName();

    [DataMember]
    [XmlElement]
    public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Nodes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nodesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nodesField = value;
        }
    }



    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        this.nodesField = System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.ReadNodes(reader);
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.WriteNodes(writer, this.Nodes);
    }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName ExportSchema(System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas)
    {
        System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.AddDefaultSchema(schemas, typeName);
        return typeName;
    }
}
```

client code is

```
           ServiceReference2.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();


        ServiceReference2.getNewsRequest k = new ServiceReference2.getNewsRequest();

        k.getNewsRequestObject = new ServiceReference2.GetNewsRequestStructure();
        k.getNewsRequestObject.LastReceivedNewsItemId = "10000";
        k.getNewsRequestObject.NumberOfRequestedNews = "5";
        k.getNewsRequestObject.ServiceToken = "";
        k.getNewsRequestObject.SPAGovernmentSectorKey = "";
        k.getNewsRequestObject.SubServiceObject = new ServiceReference2.SubServicesStructure { SubServiceId = "1", SubServiceDescription = "desc" };
        k.getNewsRequestObject.TypeOfData = ServiceReference2.TypeOfDataType.All;
        k.yefiSOAPHeaderElement = new ServiceReference2.YefiHeader();
          k.yefiSOAPHeaderElement.ServiceID = "1";
        k.yefiSOAPHeaderElement.SourceID = "2";
        k.yefiSOAPHeaderElement.SourceName = "genral";

        var t = client.getNews( k);
        // Always close the client.
        client.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you pass List<NewsListStructure> to response.getNewsResponseObject.Item. According to the definition of your class, response.getNewsResponseObject.Item can only accept Object type, not List<Object> type.

[image]

There are two solutions. The first is to modify the getNewsResponseStructure class, as shown below:

```
 public class getNewsResponseStructure
    {

        // [DataMember]
        private List<Object> itemField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("getNewsResponseDetailObject", typeof(GetNewsOutputStructure))]
        //  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ServiceError", typeof(CommonErrorStructure))]
        [XmlElement]


        [DataMember]
        public List<Object> Item
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The second is to create NewsListStructure and pass it to response.getNewsResponseObject.Item:

```
 NewsListStructure news = new NewsListStructure();
 response.getNewsResponseObject.Item = news;
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured where is my fault but your reply helped me

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in my Client i tried to sent a diffrent type of object that i cast it in the service

this the wrong

```
response.getNewsResponseObject.Item = newsList;
```

this is true

```
  response.getNewsResponseObject.Item = getNewsOutputStructure;
```

becouse in service i told it i will sent to you an

```
GetNewsOutputStructure object not List<NewsListObject>
```

in service

```
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("getNewsResponseDetailObject", typeof(GetNewsOutputStructure), Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
```